# Bash , listing files according to the file names with numbers and strings

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to sort the files based on their files names
first sort based on number, then sort based on the letters it has. 
the numbers are the age, so the adult will be the last. 
if the same numbers are used, sort based on rep1,rep2, and rep 3

the original files are ls like this

```
abc.0.5
abc.1.2
abc.15.3
abc.2.3
abc.35.5dpp
abc.35.5dpp.rep2
abc.7.3
abc.adult
abc.adult.rep2
abc.adult.rep3
```

the result should be

```
abc.0.5
abc.1.2
abc.2.3
abc.7.3
abc.15.3
abc.35.5dpp
abc.35.5dpp.rep2
abc.adult
abc.adult.rep2
abc.adult.rep3
```

I have tried

```
ls -v a*| sed 's/\.adult\./.99./' | sort -V | sed 's/\.99\./.adult./'
```

But it won't order correctly if there is dpp or rep after the numbers and adult.

Comment: err, `x*`? Your filenames all start with `abc`. (This is an issue for reproducibity/ability to test answers by modifying your sample).

Comment: thank you ! I edited my question!

Comment: BTW, *in general*, it's not good form to assume that filenames won't have newlines in them (and thus that they can be represented in line-oriented files and streamed through tools like `sed` or `sort` with one record per file at all). There's a reason modern GNU tools support `sort -z` and `xargs -0` and the like, and why `find -print0` is preferred when working with names from untrusted sources. (See also [ParsingLs](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to force `adult` to be last, just move it to the end by doing two separate batches, one of filenames that include that string, and another batch of filenames that *don't*. That is:

```
shopt -s extglob nullglob
print_lines() { (( $# )) && printf '%s\n' "$@"; }

{ print_lines abc!(*adult*) | sort -V; print_lines abc*adult* | sort -V; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
ls -v a* | sed 's/\.adult\./.99./' | sort -t. -k2,2n -k3,3n | sed 's/\.99\./.adult./'
```

Comment: `sort -V` is a GNU extension that tries to follow version-number conventions (splitting on `.`s and sorting the pieces independently). It *does* have some applicability.

Answer (score 0):

This one do the job

```
ls -l abc* | awk '{print $9}'| sed 's/\.adult/.99/' | sort -V  | sed 's/\.99/.adult/'
```

Comment: `ls -l | awk '{print $9}'`? Why? You're breaking filenames with spaces, and for no good reason when you could just leave out the `-l` and not need to strip the extra data at all. (Also, any files that started out with `.99` will be changed to `.adult`).